# Coordinates won't disappear

Tags: java, swing

This is an assignment to display coordinates of a mousepressed event on a JFrame using a JPanel.  I've satisfied all the requirements except that the old coordinates must disappear when the new ones appear. I'm sure I'm missing a concept in here somewhere but after hours of reading and trial and error I cannot get them to disappear.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Coords{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Runner();
    }
}

class Runner{
    public Runner(){
                         
        MyFrame displayWindow = new MyFrame();
        displayWindow.setSize(300,100);     
        displayWindow.setVisible(true);   
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        displayWindow.getContentPane().add(panel, "Center");
        displayWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame{
        
    public MyFrame(){
        
        System.out.println(
          "Some text on command line");          
    }    
}

class Panel extends JPanel{
    int xCoor;
    int yCoor;
    
    public Panel(){
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseProc());  
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g){    
        g.drawString("x = " + xCoor + ", y = " + yCoor, xCoor, yCoor);
    }
}

class MouseProc extends MouseAdapter{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        ((Panel)e.getComponent()).xCoor = e.getX();
        ((Panel)e.getSource()).yCoor = e.getY();
        e.getComponent().repaint();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: `public void paint(Graphics g){` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g){` for any `JComponent` but more importantly (for either), any override should immediately call the `super` method (which will erase the BG).

Comment: Override method [paintComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)) rather than method `paint` and the first line of the method must be a call to the superclass method, i.e. `super.paintComponent(g)`. Refer to lesson [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) in Oracle's java tutorials.

Comment: Got it done,  thanks for the help!